# javascript class not working when written to div using getElementById

Tags: javascript, class, getelementbyid

I have been using a datepicker js class known as tcal.  After you link to the class on your server, you can call it with one line of code.

in header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script>
```

html

```
Pick date: <input type="text" size=8 name="eventdate" class="tcal" value=>
```

It has been working fine.

However, to streamline a page, I am now trying to take it out of the html and display it in a div only when a user clicks on it using getElementById.  while I can display the input box ok, when written to the browser this way, the class no longer seems to work.

js

```
function pickDate() {
document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = 'Pick date: <input type="text" size=8 name="eventdate" class="tcal" value=>';
}
```

html

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="pickDate();">Pick Date</a><div id="show"></div>
```

When user clicks, input box appears.  However, datepicker calendar does not pop up when you click in tox.  Does anyone know why tcal is not working when written to browser this way?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there any difference between `pickDatel()` and `pickDate()` you are calling?

Comment: the reason is that you input box is adding in the dom later your datepicker code is initialized just reinitialize datepicker code

Comment: dhaval that was typo.  Rohit, how do I reinitialize datepicker code?

Comment: i see tcal.js you dont have the handle to initialize the code so see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason for this happening is that you are adding input box in the dom later your datepicker code is initialized just reinitialize datepicker code

as i see your library may don't have a code to initialize is seperately you can do hide and show instead of adding into the dom later, if the text box will be available in the starting of page ready it will be initialized so use the following code

**html -**

```
<div id="something" style="display:none;">Pick date: <input type="text" size=8 name="eventdate" class="tcal" value=></div>
```

**js -**

```
document.getElementById('something').style.display="block";
```

Comment: I don't recognize that js syntax.  Can I just display it in a function as in.. function showDate() { something.display:block; } and call that function?

Comment: sorry i forgot that you are not using jquery, and yes you can use `.style.display="block"` and i updated my answer also